# Javascript: how i use a ''global variable'' for 2 different html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I´m using 2 different html and both use the same Javascript file.

The Javascript File does this

```
var problem;

function login() {
    const login = document.getElementById('login');

    const nome = document.getElementById('lnome');
    const pass = document.getElementById('lpass');

    const item = {
        Username: nome.value.trim(),
        Password: pass.value.trim()
    };
  fetch(uri, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      problem = res; //HERE need to put into the 'problem' the value of the res
      window.location.href = url_1; // This calls index_2.html
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Unable to Login.', error));
}
```

The above code is used in index_1.html

```
$(function () {
    var $users_A = $('#users_A');
        $.ajax({
            url: uri_1,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + problem);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $users_A.append('<h4>PROBLEM RESOLVED</h4>');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
                $users_A.append('<h4>DON'T WORK</h4>');
            }
        });
    });
```

The code above is used in index_2.html

When I run the program, the variable problem doesn´t not contain the information in 'res' so it gets undefined, how I resolve this problem?

Any answer is welcome

Comment: Are you asking how to persist data across two separate page loads in JavaScript?  You essentially need a place to save that data.  If you want to save it in the browser, `localStorage` or a cookie are reasonable approaches.  If you want to save it on the server, you might make an AJAX request to the server to persist that data.

Comment: Something like that, in the fetch function give a "push" of the variable 'problem' and in ajax get the "pull" of the variable 'problem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Global variable is only Global to the currently loaded page that uses it. It's not global to all pages that may reuse the same code. If you need data to be available to all pages for a single user, store the data in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). If  you need data to be shared amongst all users on all pages, you'll need to store the data on the server.

Comment: Its a single user but my problem is using the variables, so in that case I need to do something like [ localStorage.setItem(problem, res); ] in the fetch function so when I call the ajax method I said in the index2.html, the variable problem gets the res, correct???

Comment: @JoséCarlos Yes. On one page  you can set a `localStorage` value and then you can pick up that value (or even change it) on any other page.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is a Single Page App (SPA), or in other words, a single page with javascript magic that changes what is loaded in for the html.

Seems a little complicated but could you get javascript to return the html depending on... something in the DOM?